# How to implement boundaries in SLSQP optimization in Python

Tags: python

I have a code in python 2.7.12 that works well, it is just annoying having to input "b" as many times as there are parameters. Can anyone suggest a way for me to change this such that python assumes the value unless specified otherwise?

```html
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pi = math.pi
print "Enter a Value for m"
m = int(raw_input());


def objective(x):  # Definining minimization function
# in function range(1,m) 1 is included and m is excluded. So effectively we go from 1 to m-1.
        first = 0.0
        second = 0.0
        for j in range(1, m):
            temporary_sum_first = 0.0
            temporary_sum_second = 0.0
            for i in range(0, m):
                temporary_sum_first += (x[i] * math.cos(2*pi*i*j/m))
                temporary_sum_second += ((-x[i])*i* math.sin(2*pi*i*j/m))

            first = first + math.pow(temporary_sum_first, 2)
            second = second + math.pow(temporary_sum_second, 2)
           
        Fmin=first+second
        return Fmin

def constraint1(x): #   The sum of all solution coeff. = 1
    sum_xi = 1
    for i in range(m):
        sum_xi = sum_xi - x[i]
    return sum_xi

x0 = []
for i in range(0,m):
        x0.append( float(input('Enter Initial Guesses for x[' + str(i) + ']:'))) ### guess must be <1 but > -1


print('Function Value Evaluated at Guesses = ' + str(objective(x0)))

print ('Placing Bounds on xi (-1 < b < 1)')
#Bounds placed on xi
b = (-1.0,1.0) #No reason coeff can't be negative
bnds = []
for i in range(m):
        bnds.append(input('Enter Bounds for x[' +str(i) + ']:')) ###enter 'b'
# sol coeff. have equal limits
con1 = {'type': 'eq','fun': constraint1}
solution = minimize(objective,x0,method = 'SLSQP',bounds = bnds, tol = 10e-10, constraints = con1)
x = solution.x ##^^^ Sequential Least Squares Programming Optimization method


#Displaying solution set
print('Optimized Coefficients')
for i in range (m):
        print('x[' + str(i)+'] =' + str(x[i]))
        
print('Final Function Value Using Optimized Coefficients =  ' + str(objective(x)))
```

ps. 10, constraints = con1 should be on the same line as the previous one